# Adding data to ng-repeat from addEventListener function doesn't update DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I add data to an array in $scope by using addEventListener function, the new data can be logged in console,but the DOM repeated by ng-repeat doesn't change

```
angular.module('module', [])
.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
  $scope.init = function () {
    $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      // the bottom of window
      var windowBottom = e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + e.target.documentElement.clientHeight
      // top of loading div
      var loadingTop = document.getElementById('loading').offsetTop
      if (windowBottom >= loadingTop) {
        $scope.list.push($scope.list.length + 1)
        console.log($scope.list)
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="module">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div style="height: 100%" ng-controller="controller" ng-init="init()">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="scroller">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="i in list">{{i}}</div>
        <div id="loading" class="loading">Loading...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background-color: #eee;
}
#wrapper{
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
}
.card{
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.loading{
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

What I expected is, when I scroll to the loading div at bottom of document the new data will be pushed in the array of $scope, and the DOM repeat by ng-repeat will change by the same time, but it doesn't work.

The list data could be logged in console.log, but the DOM didn't change

Run Demo:[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/nihapenexe/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: please check the answer whether this is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Friend `$scope` is not updated when we call an event handler in angular code. For that, you have to use `$scope.apply` after the event handler

```js
angular.module('module', [])
.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
  $scope.init = function () {
    $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      // 窗口底部
      var windowBottom = e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + e.target.documentElement.clientHeight
      // 加载div顶部
      var loadingTop = document.getElementById('loading').offsetTop
      if (windowBottom >= loadingTop) {
        // if ($scope.flag) {
          $scope.list.push($scope.list.length + 1)
          console.log($scope.list)
        // }
      }
      $scope.$apply()
    })
  }
  
})
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background-color: #eee;
}
#wrapper{
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
}
.card{
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.loading{
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="module">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Document</title>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div style="height: 100%" ng-controller="controller" ng-init="init()">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="scroller">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="i in list track by $index">{{i}}</div>
        <div id="loading" class="loading">加载中</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`